# How do I convert a swf vector animation to an animated svg or sequence of still svg's?

Tags: flash, svg

How do I convert a swf vector animation to an animated svg or sequence of still svg's?

Thanks!

p.s. Please don't mention www.eprg.org/~sgp/swf2svg.html. It hasn't been updated since 2000, and I'm looking for a local solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, but have you tried out this tool?

http://mgatelabs.com/cms/flashexploit/FRONT/

It seems to be locally run, which is something you said you're looking for.

Comment: Just tried that, and it only generates static svg, not animated svg